# which module(s) shall I unload to disable a wifi adapter?

Tags: wifi, module

My T400 laptop has an internal wifi adapter. It sometimes works and sometimes don't. I use an external wifi adapter, and want to disable the internal one so that it won't suddenly work again and suspiciously interfere with other things.

How can I find out which module(s) to unload?

Here is the current output, with the external wifi adapter working and the internal one not:

```
$ lsmod | grep -i wifi
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl8192c_common,rtl_usb,rtl8192cu
mac80211              786432  4 rtl_usb,rtl8192cu,rtlwifi,rtl8xxxu
cfg80211              634880  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
```

and

```
$ lspci -knn |grep -i net -A3
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10f5] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:20ee]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2937] (rev 03)
```

Comment: You can disable the internal wifi adapter and other hardware in the BIOS on ThinkPads. The setting is probably under `Security -> I/O Port Access -> Wireless LAN` (don't have a T400 handy).